Trouble accessing saved_tensors in Jacobian Vector Product in Pytorch
I am trying to write a custom jvp (Jacobian vector product) function to extend PyTorch Autograd for my use-case. I am having trouble accessing ctx.saved_tensors, but I can access them if I save them directly instead. Here is an example code which works, but without using saved_tensors. Is this the intended way to implement such functions?
class CustomFunction(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
        # Save input for backward and jvp # Doesn't work.
        ctx.input = input
        return input ** 2

    @staticmethod
    def jvp(ctx, grad_input):
        # (input,) = ctx.saved_tensors # Throws error because saved_tensors is empty
        input = ctx.input
        del ctx.input
        return 2 * input * grad_input
    

x = torch.randn(3, requires_grad=True)
v = torch.randn(3)
with torch.autograd.forward_ad.dual_level():
    dual_x = torch.autograd.forward_ad.make_dual(x, v)
    dual_y = CustomFunction.apply(dual_x)
    y, jvp = torch.autograd.forward_ad.unpack_dual(dual_y)

print(y, jvp)

PS. I would really like a recommendation for an introductory guide to writing jvp functions.
